# Close panel from link in listview

Tags: jquery-mobile, angularjs

I have a jquery mobile page which has a panel. Inside the panel I have a listview, and on each   listitem there is a  where I've added a data-rel="close" attribute. I want to be able to close the panel when ever a listitem is clicked.

Note that I also has a binding to angular.

```
<ul data-role="listview" data-icon="arrow-l" class="ui-icon-alt" data-inset="true" >
        <li ng-repeat="task in tasks" >                                
            <a href="#" ng-click="selectTask(task)" data-rel="close">{{task.Name}}</a>                        
        </li>            
    </ul>
```

I've testes on a link outside the listview and it works fine. I'm not sure id angularjs is playing a trick on me here or it is something else.

best regards
Rasmus

Comment: Did you ever solve this, or file a bug report?

Comment: I was wondering the same thing as roviuser, this seems to be an issue with 1.4-alpha.1 as well.

Answer (score 2):

Markup

```
<a href="#" id="closepanel" ng-click="selectTask(task)" data-rel="close">{{task.Name}}</a>
```

JS

```
$('#closepanel').on('click', function {} {
 $( "#PanelID" ).panel( "close" );
});
```

Comment: Sure it will work using jquery, but the markup edition does not work when the <a> is inside a list view...And I want to know why :)

Comment: Just found out this has nothing to do with AngularJS, it's only related to JQM